# Subscribe to child component's Observable (valueChanges)

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I thought to have a simple problem, but i am having a hard time finding confirmation if my solution is "correct"

I have a child component `SearchComponent` with a `formControl`

```js
@Component({
    selector : "my-search",
    inputs : ["placeholder"],
    template : `
      <div class="searchForm">
        <input type="text" [placeholder]="placeholder" [formControl]="search"/>
      </div>
    `
})
export class SearchComponent {

    search = new FormControl();
    public searchValues : Observable<string>;


    constructor() {
        this.searchValues  = this.search.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(400) 
            .distinctUntilChanged(); 
    }

}
```

I am using this in the parent component's template

```
<div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
    <my-search [placeholder]="'search'"></my-search>
</div>
```

I now want to subscribe to the `searchValues` Observable from within the parent. The best i came up with is:

```js
export class MyListComponent implements AfterContentInit {

    @ViewChild(SearchComponent) searchComponent: SearchComponent;

    constructor(private myService: MyService ) {

    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.searchComponent.searchValues.subscribe(s=>this.search(s))
    }

    private search(s: string) {
        this.foos = this.myService.find(s); 
    }

    foos: Observable<[Foo]>; // used on a ngFor | async

}
```

Is this recommended approach? Is there no better way to define the contract between the components (like can be done with `@Input` and `@Output`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily use @Output for this.
In the search component you could add one like:

```
@Output() searchEvent: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

Then subscribe to the text changes and (re)emit them:

```
this.search.valueChanges
        .debounceTime(400) 
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe((event) => this.searchEvent.emit(event));
```

After that you have the Output that you can use in any parent component. Without any need for a component reference (ViewChild).

**Edit**

One way to use this would be to have a Subject in the parent component that you push changes to `updateStream = new Subject()` and the event handler `(searchEvent) = "updateStream.next($event)"`.

Then you can create the Observable like:

```
foo = updateStream.flatMap((s) => myService.find(s))
```

Comment: Thanks(!) That makes sense, however it does not expose an `Observable`, which could then be further processed as such  by the parent. However i do like the simplicity of this, but on the other hand would love to see observables as the contract instead of `EventEmitter`

Comment: It actually extends the Subject type, since it can both [emit and subscribe to](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html). In the parent components you could have an Observable/Subject that you can push the event changes to and merge/map that to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the extra edit. This works perfectly and is "clean". I wonder if they will make it easier to subscribe to a `@output` `Source` such as `EventEmitter` (but too be honest not even sure what that should look like however) . Thanks again for your help :)